# What is the proper way to handle unique id in a REST architecture?

Tags: api, rest, mobile

My application is two parts :

- an `android app` that lets the user creates comments on stuff. Each comment has a unique id (a string)
- a server with a REST api (json based) that gathers the data. The server generates the unique id.

The `android app` creates a new comment by POSTing the comment data to the `server`, minus the unique id (it gets generated by the `server` upon the comment creation). 
The unique id will be used in the subsequent requests  (For example : `<myserver>/api/v1/comment/<id>`)

**The question is**  after the POST, the `server` needs a way to tell the `android app` what the id of the newly created comment is.

What is the REST way to do get the new id ?

Note : I would like to avoid to create an extra call to get a new identifier and then to post my comment.

Comment: Take a look at the [AtomPub](http://bitworking.org/projects/atom/rfc5023.html#crwp) protocol, it shows one way of doing it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-10.2.2

You respond with a `201 Created` status and a `Location` header containing the URI to the created resource.

Answer (score 0):

just reply to the POST with the id